# 3 divs in row with auto width adjust

Tags: jquery, css

I got 3 divs that:

- need to to be side by side ( in a row)
- all have a background imgage
- the center div need to adjust the width automatic, center div's width dependance on the content that have been inserted into the div( longer text = longer width
- center div needs to be at the center of the page too.
- the divs on sides have diffrent backgrounds img.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="spanl"></div>
<div class="center">Headline</div>
<div class="spanr"></div>
```

note that the divs in sides are empty.

something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/fsnuh/134/

Is this possible to do with css or css3? If not how can I do it with jquery or raw javascript?

Comment: how much your auto width div (centered one) can expand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tables for the win! [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VJyBw/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #container {  display: table; width: 100% }
            #left, #right { display: table-cell; width: 50%; background: #ffd }
            #content { display: table-cell }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="content">
                <div style="white-space: nowrap" onclick="this.firstChild.nodeValue += ' blah'">blah</div>
            </div>
            <div id="right"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I love this solution, but as I look at it, I ask if what you've really observed is that it is now OK to use tables for layout. (Again.)

Answer (score 1):

Give the header a fixed width if you can. Then use jQuery to calculate the widths and set them accordingly.

Here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rniestroj/fsnuh/135/

html:

```
<div>
     <h3 class="headline2">
     <div class="spanl"></div>
     <div class="center">Kontakt 11111111111 22222</div>
     <div class="spanr"></div>
     </h3>
</div>
```

css:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;    
}

h3{
    width: 600px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.spanr, .spanl {
    background: url("../img/headline2.png") no-repeat scroll right center gold;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    position: relative;
    width: 33%;
}
.center {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E6B043;
    float: left;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: auto;
}
```

js:

```
var h3Width = $("h3").width();
var centerWidth = $(".center").width();
var asideWidth = 0;
asideWidth = ((h3Width - centerWidth) / 2) - 12;

$(".spanl").width(asideWidth );
$(".spanr").width(asideWidth );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS only solution:

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fsnuh/137/).

**HTML:**

```
<div id="headlines">
    <h3 class="headline2">
        <span>Kontakt</span>
    </h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#headlines {
    background-image: url('../img/headline2.png'), url('../img/headline2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center, right center
}
.headline2, .headline2 > span {
    height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 33px
}
.headline2 > span {
    background-color: #E6B043;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px
}
```